# VB Seat booking file outputting incorrectly

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a seat booking program for coursework in which a user selects which row he/she wishes to book seats in, and then the number of seats they wish to book.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim rowNumber As Integer
    Dim SeatsData As String(,) = {{"booked", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10"}, {"booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked", "booked"}, {"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10"}, {"D1", "booked", "booked", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10"}, {"E1", "E2", "booked", "booked", "booked", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E10"}}

    If ListBox2.Text = "A" Then
        rowNumber = 0
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "B" Then
        rowNumber = 1
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "C" Then
        rowNumber = 2
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "D" Then
        rowNumber = 3
    ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "E" Then
        rowNumber = 4
    End If

    FindSeats(rowNumber, ListBox1.Text, SeatsData)

End Sub
Function FindSeats(ByVal RowNumber As Integer, ByVal NumSeats As Integer, SeatsData As Array) As String

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim arrayPos As Integer = 0
    Dim largestStreak As Integer = 0
    Dim FirstSeat As String = 0
    Dim LastSeat As String = 0
    Dim foundSeats As Boolean = False
    Dim returnMsg As String = ""

    Do While foundSeats = False
        Dim seatChar As String = SeatsData(RowNumber, arrayPos)
        arrayPos = arrayPos + 1

        If seatChar = "booked" Then
            i = 0
        Else
            If i = 0 Then
                FirstSeat = seatChar
            End If
            i = i + 1

            If i > largestStreak Then
                largestStreak = i
            End If

        End If

        If i = NumSeats Then
            LastSeat = seatChar
            If FirstSeat = LastSeat Then
                returnMsg = "Found seat: " + FirstSeat
            Else
                returnMsg = "Found seats: " + FirstSeat + " - " + LastSeat
            End If
            MsgBox(returnMsg)
            Label3.Text = returnMsg
            foundSeats = True
            Exit Do
        End If

        If arrayPos = 10 Then
            returnMsg = "Not enough available seats, maximum available seats: " + CStr(largestStreak)
            MsgBox(returnMsg)
            Label3.Text = returnMsg
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Function
End Class
```

The issue I am having is that when a user selects the number of seats they want but not which row they want them for, the program automatically books seats in row A. How do I fix this? Also when A user selects a row but not a number of seats (or vice versa) the form goes to code and outputs the following error message: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

How do I fix these errors? I am very new to VB so if any of this is obvious then I apologise!

Comment: Some tips: Give your controls meaningful names. `ListBox1` sucks, `NumberOfSeatsListBox` makes sense. Also, seperate your business logic from your UI. That will make it easier to test your code.

Answer (score 3):

You get the exception because you call `FindSeats` like this:

```
FindSeats(rowNumber, ListBox1.Text, SeatsData)
```

Note that the signature of `FindSeats` is actually

```
Function FindSeats(RowNumber As Integer, NumSeats As Integer, SeatsData As Array) As String
```

So you pass a string `ListBox1.Text` as `NumSeats` parameter, which is an `Integer`. Since you use `Option Strict Off`, VB.Net tries to implicitly cast the string in `ListBox1.Text` into an `Integer`.

This fails if `ListBox1.Text` is empty, and that's what the exception message it telling you:

> Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

First, turn `Option Strict` to `On`, then you'll see all those nifty implicit conversions that will bite you at runtime. Go on and replace them with safe explicit conversions that make sense.

Think about how you want to handle the case when the user clicks `Button1` without selecting something in `ListBox1` before.

Maybe you want to use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to handle such cases, or maybe preselect a valid value in `ListBox1`